# Tensorflow 1.8 memory still kept on GPU after closing session

Tags: c++, tensorflow

In my company we are currently developing an application which extensively uses GPU processing: Deep learning, own CUDA implementation and 3D Visualization using DirectX. GPU memory access is important for each process. We have came accross one problem with TensorFlow (TF) when DeepLearning (DL) model is used: after closing session for TF with DL model GPU memory is not released. It is freed only when an application process is finished. This creates serious problem for our application because other processing requests after DL call cannot be done due to insufficient memory. I have found that there are some solution where TF session is started in another process, but we have concern about performance that huge memory would have to be copied between processed. Is there any other solution for TF or new version has better solution?

Comment: You can optionally add more details on how you create the session and how you release the session. Things like `tf.GPUOptions` you are passion to the session and like...

Comment: @prosti thank you for the answer.

Comment: In general we use three layer approach from c# by c++/cli into c++. 
On c++ side we have StartSession and StopSession method which are called by c# when processing is started and finished, respectively:

Comment: `void Encoder::StartSession()
{
 if (session != nullptr)
  return;
 auto sessionOptions = tensorflow::SessionOptions();
 sessionOptions.config.gpu_options.allow_growth = true;
 session = std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session>(sessionOptions);
 if (session == nullptr)
 {
 }
}'

Comment: void Encoder::StopSession()
{
 if (session != nullptr)
 {
  session->Close();
  session = nullptr;
 }
}

Comment: StartSession is called when GUI c# application is started, later calls for processing are done from another thread (background worker) to avoid GUI blocking. When processing is finished then stop session is called in the calling thread. This can be the reason why resources are not released?

Comment: Language mixtures may bring some unfortunate here. TF is written in Python, C++, CUDA, but I think the session thing is Python based and the numerical operation with tensors are written in C++. Try also to release the graph object from the session if possible.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow Session owns resources that must be explicitly freed by invoking the `close()` method. You need to use that method explicitly.

Since instances of a Session are thread-safe and multiple threads may access the same Session object, make sure you release everything that may be connected with the Session object since that may hold the Session from closing correctly.

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19731) is how after closing a sessison sub-process the problem with memory allocation has been fixed.